# Child component calls parent function when rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component called 'Display' with a function 'selectRow(param)' which is passed to a 'Row' component to be called when a button on Row is clicked, but as soon as the 'Row's components are rendered, the function is called. How can I set the 'selectRow' function to only be called when the buttons are clicked?

***Display***

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Row from './Row';

import {  generateRows, rearrangeCards } from '../helpers';

function Display({ displayDeck }) {

  const [deck, setDeck] = useState(displayDeck);

  const selectRow = (param) => {
    console.log(param)
  }

  let rows =  generateRows(deck);

  return (
    <div>
    {
      Object.keys(rows).map((key, index) => {
        return <Row rowDeck={rows[key].deck} selectRow={selectRow} rowId={rows[key].id} key={index} />
      })
    }
    </div>
  );

}

export default Display;
```

***Row***

```
import React from 'react';

function Row({ rowDeck, selectRow, rowId }) {

  function handleClick() {
    selectRow(rowId)
  }

  return (
    <div className="rowContainer">
      <button type="button" id="card" onClick={handleClick()} className="rowButton">Shuffle</button>
      {rowDeck.map((card, index) => {
        return (
          <img
            key={index}
            width="100"
            alt={`card: ${card.value}-${card.suit}`}
            src={card.image}
            className="image"
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Row;
```

Comment: I think you are calling the prop function immediately when it renders by using onClick={handleClick()}  . Change it to onClick={handleClick}

Comment: Yep, you're right, thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onClick={handleClick}
```

This should be your handleClick method.  You don't need the () inside the onClick, and I believe that's the what happens when you do it that way.  Please try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This

`onClick={handleClick()}`

should be:

`onClick={handleClick}`

What you pass to the `onClick` event handler, is a reference to a function, which will be called when the event gets triggered. There's no need to call the function inside the { curly braces }, as it will get executed immediately.